# How to set Filter to be applied for content-type "html/text" ONLY?

Tags: java, filter, content-type, servlet-filters, cache-control

I wrote following code.

```
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Date;

public class CacheFilter implements Filter {

public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
                     FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

    HttpServletResponse resp = (HttpServletResponse) response;
    resp.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-store, no-cache,must-revalidate,max-age=0");
    resp.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");

    chain.doFilter(request, response);
}

public void destroy() {
//delegate.destroy();
}
public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) {
//delegate.destroy();
}
}
```

and here's the maping code in web.xml file

```
  <filter>
     <filter-name>CacheFilter</filter-name>
     <filter-class>com.util.CacheFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CacheFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
```

This thing works but this filter gets applied for all the content, thus slowing my site's performance. I want this filter to be applied for content type "text/html" only. This can be easily achieved through **ExpiresFilter** like this

```
 <init-param>
     <param-name>ExpiresByType text/html</param-name>
     <param-value>access plus 0 seconds</param-value>
</init-param>
```

but how to achieve it in this code?
I'd appreciate your earliest help.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to write Response Wrapper to modify the response from servlet-

See this links- http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0400__Servlet/Filterthatusesaresponsewrappertoconvertalloutputtouppercase.htm

http://sqltech.cl/doc/oas10gR31/web.1013/b28959/filters.htm

http://software.it168.com/manual/servlet/0596005725_jsvltjspckbk-chp-19-sect-7.html

-Thanks